# Create data ranges based on list of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of dates  like this (no gaps, each calendar date):

| DateKey | Valid |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | 0 |
| 2021-01-05 | 0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 |
| 2021-01-07 | 1 |

I would like to convert them using T-SQL to date ranges considering valid dates **only**.

So the results would be:

| ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-07 |

Grouping simply by Valid flag rtutns wrong results:

```
select  min(dateKey),max(dateKey)
from #t 
group by Valid
```

If I knew how to assign a unique value for each continuous segment of valid dates, that would solve my problem. Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option using the window function `sum() over()`

```
Select ValidFrom = min(DateKey)
      ,ValidTo   = max(DateKey)
 From (
        Select *
              ,Grp = sum(case when Valid=0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by DateKey)
        from YourTable
      ) A
 Where Valid=1
 Group By Grp
```

**Returns**

```
ValidFrom   ValidTo
2021-01-01  2021-01-03
2021-01-06  2021-01-07
```

Comment: Or, to obfuscate a _bit_, `sum( 1 - Valid )`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following may work for you:

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (Dt DATE, Valid BIT)
INSERT @Dates
VALUES('2021-01-01',    1),
      ('2021-01-02',    1),
      ('2021-01-03',    1),
      ('2021-01-04',    0),
      ('2021-01-05',    0),
      ('2021-01-06',    1),
      ('2021-01-07',    1)


SELECT MIN(dt.Dt) AS BeginRange,
       MAX(dt.Dt) AS EndRange
FROM (
        SELECT d.Dt,
            DATEDIFF(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Dt), d.Dt) AS DtRange
        FROM @Dates d
        WHERE Valid = 1
    ) AS dt
GROUP BY dt.DtRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've just found the solution of my problem:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197972/convert-list-of-dates-in-a-date-range-in-sql-server

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (dt DATE);

INSERT INTO @t (dt)
VALUES ('20180202')
    ,('20180203')
    ,('20180204')
    ,('20180205')
    ,('20180209')
    ,('20180212')
    ,('20180213');

WITH c
AS (
    SELECT dt
        ,dateadd(day, - 1 * dense_rank() OVER (orderby dt), dt) AS grp
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT min(dt) AS start_range
    ,max(dt) AS end_range
FROM c
GROUP BY grp;
```